# Where to find neo4j config files in google vm

Tags: google-cloud-platform, neo4j, virtual-machine, graph-databases

Where can I find the neo4j config files in a google vm? I need to uncomment a line in them to allow remote connection to the database.

Comment: What is the name of the file? Then use this command: `sudo find / -name FILENAME -print`.

Comment: How have you proceeded with the database installation?

Answer (score 0):

Usually on linux in /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/configuration/file-locations/

On docker/k8s, you can pass in config options from the outside via environment / helm

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/docker/configuration/

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/kubernetes/